# How to test a method that uses package_info in Flutter?

Tags: unit-testing, dart, flutter, package-info

I am writing a Flutter plugin that checks the Play Store or App Store to see if the app needs to be updated. I'm using the `package_info` package to determine the version of the app that the user has. My code looks like this:

```
getVersionStatus() {
    PackageInfo packageInfo = await PackageInfo.fromPlatform();
    localVersion = packageInfo.version;
    ...
}
```

I want to test this method, but if it run it as a unit test the `fromPlatform` call just hangs and times out the test. Is there a more elegant way to solve this than passing in a `testing` boolean? I.e:

```
if (testing) {
    PackageInfo packageInfo = await PackageInfo.fromPlatform();
    localVersion = packageInfo.version;
} else {
    localVersion = '0.0.0'
}
```

Should the `package_info` package provide a way to catch errors? Is there a way to tell if the method is being run by a test?

Comment: There are methods on MethodChannel to register mock callbacks to send mock returns

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Like Günter said, you can mock *PackageInfo* by installing a [mock method handler](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/MethodChannel/setMockMethodCallHandler.html) in the MethodChannel for the plugin:

```
void packageInfoMock() {
  const MethodChannel('plugins.flutter.io/package_info').setMockMethodCallHandler((MethodCall methodCall) async {
    if (methodCall.method == 'getAll') {
      return <String, dynamic>{
        'appName': 'ABC',  // <--- set initial values here
        'packageName': 'A.B.C',  // <--- set initial values here
        'version': '1.0.0',  // <--- set initial values here
        'buildNumber': ''  // <--- set initial values here
      };
    }
    return null;
  });
}
```

Comment: Oh I didn't consider overwriting plugin channels, that works! Thanks.

Comment: Don't forget to 
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

Answer (score 7):

```dart
PackageInfo.setMockInitialValues(appName: "abc", packageName: "com.example.example", version: "1.0", buildNumber: "2", buildSignature: "buildSignature");
```

Comment: See "[Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/128421)". While this might be technically correct, it doesn't explain why it solves the problem or should be the selected answer. We should educate along with helping solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I delegated the PackageInfo access to a repository object. This repo then is easy to mock. This also works for package_info_plus.